# Converting Coord extend Lambert II (WGS84) to Geographical coordonate (lat lng) using ESRI API

Tags: convert, coordinates, esri-geodatabase, arcgis-online-basemaps, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I am using the esri API and I am facing an issue to convert Coordinate extend Lambert II to Geographical coordinate.

> For example :  x : 633951 y : 1959059.

I have try to use webMercatorUtils like that :

```
webMercatorUtils.xyToLngLat(X, Y);
```

But it returns the wrong coordinate.

I also tried to convert by the class Point like that :

`let mypoint = new Point(this.bassinCoord[i].xLieu, this.bassinCoord[i].yLieu, new SpatialReference({ wkid: 27582}))`;

I use the wkid for France : cf : http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisserver/apis/rest/pcs.html

Here is my full code :

```
        while (i < this.bassinCoord.length) {
          let mypoint = new Point(X, Y, new SpatialReference({ wkid: 27582}));
          let radius = radius;
          let normalizedVal = webMercatorUtils.xyToLngLat(X, Y);
          let circle = new Circle({
            center: mypoint,
            radius: radius
          });
          let graphic = new Graphic(circle, symbol);
          gl.add(graphic);
          i++;
        }
```

I do not want to use an external library other than Esri (if possible).

Comment: You can switch to 27572 NTF (Paris) Lambert zone II. It's the same CRS. 27582 is an older definition which is no longer in the [EPSG registry](http://www.epsg-registry.org) and is deprecated in Esri software. Take a look at this [sample](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jssamples/fl_any_projection.html) maybe.

Answer (score 1):

you have two options.

1. use a [GeometryService](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jssamples/util_label_point.html) and make a web request to reproject your input point.
2. use something like [Proj4js](http://proj4js.org/):

   ```
   var wkid4269 = '+proj=longlat +a=6378137.0 // ...;  
   var wkid26912 = '+proj=utm +zone=12 +ellps=GRS80 // ...;  

   map.on("mouse-move", function(evt) {
       proj4(wkid26912, wkid4269, [evt.mapPoint.x, evt.mapPoint.y]); 
   });
   ```

i wrote a blog titled [Use Proj4js alongside the ArcGIS API for JavaScript to reproject coordinates on the fly](https://geonet.esri.com/groups/geodev/blog/2014/11/03/use-proj4js-alongside-the-arcgis-api-for-javascript-to-reproject-coordinates-on-the-fly) with more information a few years ago.

Comment: Thank you,
The things i didn't precise is that i'm in angular2..
So i can't import js inside it.. (for proj4js). My program deal with big data, and i can't send all the data on a geometryService otherwise it will kill the performance (corporate network system)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the .getLatitude and .getLongitude methods of the Point class to return coordinates in Geographical units if the spatial reference of the point is **Web Mercator or Geographic (4326)**.

```
let x = mypoint.getLatitude();
let y = mypoint.getLongitude();
```